# problem with" git add . " fatal error Browse.VC.opendb

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm trying to use `git add .` to upload my project to github, but when I use the command I keep getting this error:

```
error: open("PuzzleGame/.vs/PuzzleGame/v16/Browse.VC.opendb"): Permission denied
error: unable to index file 'PuzzleGame/.vs/PuzzleGame/v16/Browse.VC.opendb'
fatal: adding files failed
```

the only way I can go past this error is to close my visual studio!

if anybody could help me, I would be grateful.

![the same error can be seen in the image][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoaBp.jpg

Comment: You better find an appropriate `.gitignore` file for Visual Studio so that all unnecessary files are not processed by git

Comment: Add the .vs folder to your .gitignore.

Comment: Thanks @AlexLarionov

Comment: @DanielMann I will do that

Answer (score 3):

Just close the IDE(in here Visual Studio) and try it again. It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The option that works is to close the IDE (Visual Studio) and try again to add the changes from Git, that works, but it also works adding the .vs/ folder to the .gitignore to solve the problem.